# Generating Swagger 2.0 JSON from Restlet

Tags: restlet, swagger

Using Restlet 2.3.3 I've declared my Restlet Application to derive from SwaggerApplication. When I visit the default /api-docs URI, I am observing that the Swagger version of the meta data is 1.2. Subsequently, I'm not able to load this into Swagger-UI without an error.

How can I obtain Swagger 2.0 JSON from Restlet's Swagger extension? The documentation seems to suggest that it can output v2.0 JSON.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class `SwaggerApplication` only supports Swagger 1.2. If you want to use Swagger 2.0, you must attach manually the corresponding restlet to generate the content based on the class `Swagger2SpecificationRestlet` as described below:

```
public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
    Router router = new Router(getContext());

    // Configuring Swagger 2 support
    Swagger2SpecificationRestlet swagger2SpecificationRestlet
                   = new Swagger2SpecificationRestlet(this);
    swagger2SpecificationRestlet.setBasePath(
                           "http://myapp.com/api/v1");
    swagger2SpecificationRestlet.attach(router);

    return router;
}
```

With such configuration, the associated resource to get the Swagger content is attached on the path `/swagger.json`. You can notice that you can specify your own path with the method `Swagger2SpecificationRestlet#attach(Router, String)`.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Hi Thierry can you also help me out with my Swagger Restlet problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534281/swagger-not-working