# Swagger not working

Tags: java, swagger, restlet

I'm having a bit of trouble making Swagger display API docs using Restlet. What Swagger shows is just these stuff:

[image]

And checking the api-docs it only shows this:

[image]

I wonder what is wrong with my code:

```
public class MyApplication extends SwaggerApplication {
    private static final String ROOT_URI = "/";
    public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
        Router router = new Router(getContext());
        router.attach(ROOT_URI, RootServerResource.class);
        router.attach(ROOT_URI + "ping", PingServerResource.class);
        router.attach(ROOT_URI + "ping/", PingServerResource.class);
        // Some code omitted for simplicity
        return router;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are using Spring Security, use the security configuration mentioned on **[Cannot open Swagger UI in tis Version 3 in my Spring Boot Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73073519/cannot-open-swagger-ui-in-tis-version-3-in-my-spring-boot-example)** page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a look at this article:

- What can APISpark bring to your existing Web APIs (Part 2) -http://restlet.com/blog/2016/01/04/what-can-apispark-bring-to-your-existing-web-apis-part-2/

Both Swagger1 and 2 are supported by the Swagger extension of Restlet:

- **Swagger v1**

  ```
  public class ContactsApplication extends SwaggerApplication {
      public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
          Router router = new Router();
          (...)
          attachSwaggerSpecificationRestlet(router, "/docs");

          return router;
      }
  }
  ```
- **Swagger v2**

  ```
  public class ContactsApplication extends Application {
     public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
          Router router = new Router();
          (...)
          Swagger2SpecificationRestlet swagger2SpecificationRestlet
                                 = new Swagger2SpecificationRestlet(this);
          swagger2SpecificationRestlet.setBasePath("http://myapp.org/");
          swagger2SpecificationRestlet.attach(router, "/docs");
          return router;
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to add this code:

```
    // Configuring Swagger 2 support
    Swagger2SpecificationRestlet swagger2SpecificationRestlet
            = new Swagger2SpecificationRestlet(this);
    swagger2SpecificationRestlet.setBasePath("http://localhost:8080/api-docs");
    swagger2SpecificationRestlet.attach(router);
```

And point the Swagger UI to `/swagger.json`

Answer (score 0):

Swagger needs to find your API operations. I'm not sure about Restlet, in Jersey you annotate your REST resource classes with `@Api` and your methods with `@ApiOperation`. Read more here [in the swagger docs](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Annotations-1.5.X).

Comment: Also you can browse to the respective resource with `/api-docs/resource`

Comment: Did this help you at all? Then please mark the answer as correct.